# How to properly import a Gradle project into IntelliJ with dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

So, I have a fairly basic Gradle project. Everything works fine through Gradle using either "test" or "build". However, when I go to actually import this project into IntelliJ, everything seems to be added as expected except none of the dependencies make it into the build process. The Gradle tool window clearly lists the dependencies used and such, but actually trying to use these ends up with none of the packages being found. I've tried resyncing it, cleaning and rebuilding, etc. But it always ends up with none of the dependencies actually being there in IntelliJ's build process. Building from Gradle is fine.

How can I resolve this!? I tried using the "idea" plugin with the "ideaModule" task. This puts all the dependencies into there as I expect, but also overwrites all of the changes that I made (such as excluded/included source files)... And I'd need to make sure to manually run it any time I change dependencies

How can I get IntelliJ to actually recognize and build with the dependencies in the Gradle build file?

Comment: Maybe you could include your Gradle build file, or at least the ideaModule block and any other information that could be helpful.

Comment: @dlcole ugh. Tried to reproduce it and such and can't now, re-imported my Gradle project into IntelliJ and now it works...

Comment: Did you change your IntelliJ version? If this is the case, you might find the fix in the new release and an answer would be welcomed. 
Otherwise, please delete your question as it is not valid.